# Assuming responsibility for Socket from TcpClient

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient

I want to use TcpClient for simplicity of connecting, however once connected I want to hand off responsibility of the Socket to a generic data processing class (it does not care if it is UDP/TCP).  Is the code below the correct way to assume responsibility for the socket created by TcpClient?

```
    

    TcpClient client;
    Socket s;

    client.Connect(...);

    // take the socket 
    s = client.Client;
    client.Client = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `Socket.Connect` in the first place?

IIRC the `TcpClient` considers itself as the owner and will dispose the socket when finished.

Comment: 1. I wanted to use TcpClient to create the connection because I am lazy.
2. So assigning TcpClient.Client = null would not work?